# Input hours - Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, time, ionic-framework, hour

I have been trying to create a dropdown for my Ionic app where a user can select different times too book an appointment. I set it up so that the hour selected will be a value.  However, so far, I have been unable to get it to work. When I try to data bind or view the value in the console nothing appears.

Here is a snippet of what I have so far:

```
<select>
      <option ng-model="bookingInfo.hour" type="time" value="08:00"> 8:00am</option>
      <option ng-model="bookingInfo.hour" type="time" value="09:00"> 9:00am</option>
    </select>
  </label>
```

I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the list of booking timings, you can create an array inside your controller and use [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to iterate over them.

then, your `<select>` would have an `ng-model` to bind the selected value.

Here's a working example!

```js
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.bookingInfo = [
    {"hour": "8:00AM"},
    {"hour": "9:00AM"},
    {"hour": "10:00AM"},
    {"hour": "11:00AM"}
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedBooking" name="bookingInfo">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your booking time</option>
    <option value="{{info.hour}}" ng-repeat="info in bookingInfo" type="time">{{info.hour}}</option>
  </select>
  <div style="margin-top:20px">Selected time: {{selectedBooking ? selectedBooking : 'none'}}</div>
</body>
```